# CORS issue when requesting an S3 bucket

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fetch-api

I am trying to access a public S3 bucket I have made from a local dev server - https://balgores-best-kebab.s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/menu.js. I have added CORS config to the bucket, but am still getting issues. Please see screenshots

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I missing here?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not allow any headers, but you are sending headers with your request. Can you try changing your `AllowedHeaders` to this?

```
"AllowedHeaders": [
    "*"
],
```